# Parenthesis vertically misaligned in "cases" environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

I'm writing a paper using the "aps" document class, and I'm struggling with the `cases` environment -- which usually works like a charm for me. In one of my sections I present two equations that I want gathered as "cases":

```
\documentclass[aps,preprint,a4paper]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\delay}[1]{\mathcal{D}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\filter}{\mathcal{F}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        s_1 =& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
        s_1' =& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:definition-s1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would expect this to work fine and the two equations to be vertically aligned with the big opening parenthesis... but it seems that the layout comes out wrong:
[image: Misalignement of cases]
Here we see that the parenthesis is clearly shifted up with respect to the equations.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Thanks very much for your time,
Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How are the macros `\filter` and `\delay` defined. Most likely they have something in their definitions that causes the issue. Please provide us with a minimal document which starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and has the definitions of the macros in it and shows the issue.

Comment: Quite likely you have something like `\doublespacing` in your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is surely due to you having set double spacing in your document. The following example indeed shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\filter}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\delay}[1]{\mathcal{D}_{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        s_1 =& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
        s_1' =& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:definition-s1}
\end{equation}

\doublespacing

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        s_1 =& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
        s_1' =& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:definition-s2}
\end{equation}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        s_1 =& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
        s_1' =& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:definition-s3}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Equation 1 is normal, equation 2 is under the scope of `\doublespacing` and shows the problem. Equation 3 is after the cure. The magic constant 0.72 is 1.2/1.667 (1.2 is the `\arraystretch` used by `cases`, `1.667` is the `\baselinestretch` used by double spacing).

Here's how to do it for the whole document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\filter}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\delay}[1]{\mathcal{D}_{#1}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        s_1 =& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
        s_1' =& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:definition-s1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You may also want to fix the vertical spacing in matrices:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}
\pretocmd\env@matrix{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

With `revtex4-1` the correct patches should be slightly different:

```
\documentclass[
  aps,
  preprint,
  a4paper,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\filter}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\delay}[1]{\mathcal{D}_{#1}}

\makeatletter
\preprintsty@sw{%
  \patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}%
  \pretocmd\env@matrix{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}{}{}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        s_1 =& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
        s_1' =& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
    \end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
abc \\
def
\end{bmatrix}
    \label{eq:definition-s1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This way the patches will only be done when `preprint` is active.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the very comprehensive answer and the fix! That's a pity that "cases" uses the line height to compute the parenthesis' height and does not automatically vertically center the content...

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste The fault is in double spacing; no reasonable typesetting can be done with that constraint.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste I added the correct patches for `revtex4-1`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could instead use the `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\filter}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\delay}{\mathcal{D}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \bigg\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    s_1 &=& \filter \delay{3} p_2' - \filter p_1, \\
    s_1' &=& \filter \delay{2'} p_3 - \filter p_1'.
  \end{array}
  \label{eq:definition-s1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```