# in Lyx, how to reduce/increase the vertical distance within cases environment?

Tags: spacing, lyx, cases

I read some related posts however, I still cannot control the vertical distance in `cases` environment. I am using Lyx.

for example, I want to reduce the vertical distance between the two lines of the case

[image]

I copied the code from the Latex Preview

```
\[
x_{ij}^{k}=
\begin{cases}
1, & \textrm{if vehicle \ensuremath{k} travels from \ensuremath{i} to \ensuremath{j}}\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Strange… It is dissymmetric. Can you post the code that's behind?

Comment: Does your document maybe set a low-level parameter such as `\baselineskip` to a value other than `1`? Or, does your document load the `setspace` package and employ a large argument for `\setstretch`?

Comment: See also [How to decrease vertical spacing in cases environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472508/5001)

Comment: @Bernard as you noted the case is not centered regard to the brace. Additionally I want to reduce the vertical space between the two sentences.

Comment: Do you have (implicitly or explicitly) set the line spacing to double? (By implicitly I mean that if you use e.g. `revote` with the `preprint` option, you get line spacing double without explicitly asking for it.) Your output resembles https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450387, maybe either [Mico's fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472518/194703) the fixes below [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450387) will work for you.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat, yes I set my document to double space

Comment: When I compile this code, I have none of these problems. Just in case: are you sure `amsmmath` is loaded?

Comment: @Bernard, I have set the Math Options to load amsmath always.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat, I think you have helped me a lot . I have highlighted my case and changed the Paragraph Settings and set the line spacing to single and it is done. However I am still asking whether I can control the vertical distance in the case itself.

Comment: @Sabreen A simple way of increasing the distance is to add a distance after `\\ ` in the cases environment, e.g. `\[ x_{ij}^{k}=\begin{cases} 1, & \textrm{if vehicle $k$ travels from $i$ to $j$}\\[1em] 0, & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases} \]`. (This autocorrection here is starting to go on my nerves. In my above comment `revote` was meant to be `revtex`. Grrr.)

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat , when I use insert Tex code , I fail to write the double backslash like that " \\[-10pt]" . The interpreter understand it as backslash not ctr+enter .

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - I don't know Lyx, and hence I don't know what the OP's document does when he/she says that "I set my document to double space". As there's no guarantee that the document uses the `setspace` package, running `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}` is not particularly likely to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose two possibilities:

– either nest your equation in a `singlespace` environment, and use `cases*` environment from `mathtools` to simplify the code (after `&` you're in text mode automatically),

– or load the `empheq` package (which loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`) and use the eponymous environment with `align*` in the place of `cases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

Blahblahblah

\begin{singlespace}
\[ x_{ij}^{k}=\begin{cases*}
1, & if vehicle \ensuremath{k} travels from \ensuremath{i} to \ensuremath{j} \\
0, & otherwise
\end{cases*}\]
\end{singlespace}

\begin{empheq}[left={ x_{ij}^{k}=\empheqlbrace}]{align*}
1, & \quad\textrm{if vehicle \ensuremath{k} travels from \ensuremath{i} to \ensuremath{j}} \\[-2ex]
0, & \quad\textrm{otherwise}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How I use cases* in Lyx? where can I find it?

Comment: As I don't use Lyx, I have no idea, but `mathtools` is a well established extension of `amsmath`, so I suppose it must take it into account. If no one knows here, maybe there exists a forum dedicated to Lyx?